# RxJava parallel execution issue

Tags: multithreading, rx-java

I am trying to use Rx Java for parallelization. I am calling 5 methods parallely using Rx Java as follows.

```
    public Map findData(param1,param2){

               Observable<List<DataDTO>> data1 = 
                            Observable.create(s->{
                                    try {   
                                        s.onNext(method1(param1,param2));
                                    }
                                    catch(Exception e) {
                                        System.out.println("Exception happened while calculating Data");
                                        s.onError(e);
                                    }

                        });

                        Observable<List<DataDTO>> data2 = 
                                Observable.create(s->{
                                        try {   
                                            s.onNext(method2(param1,param2));
                                        }
                                        catch(Exception e) {
                                            System.out.println("Exception happened while calculating Data");
                                            s.onError(e);
                                        }
                            });


                        Observable<List<DataDTO>> data3 = 
                                Observable.create(s->{
                                        try {   
                                            s.onNext(method3(param1,param2));
                                        }
                                        catch(Exception e) {
                                            System.out.println("Exception happened while calculating Data");
                                            s.onError(e);
                                        }
                            });

                        Observable<List<DataDTO>> data4 = 
                                Observable.create(s->{
                                        try {   
                                            s.onNext(method3(param1,param2));
                                        }
                                        catch(Exception e) {
                                            System.out.println("Exception happened while calculating Data");
                                            s.onError(e);
                                        }
                            });

                        Observable<List<DataDTO>> data5 = 
                                Observable.create(s->{
                                        try {   
                                            s.onNext(method4(param1,param2));
                                        }
                                        catch(Exception e) {
                                            System.out.println("Exception happened while calculating Data");
                                            s.onError(e);
                                        }
                            });

             Observable<List<DataDTO>> mergedBean = Observable.merge(
                         data1.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),
                    data2.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),
                    data3.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),
                    data4.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()));

       Observable<List<DataDTO>> mergedBean1 = Observable.merge(mergedBean,data5.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()));

  mergedBean1.subscribe(s->combineDataMethod(s,beanMap),
                        e ->   {throw new BusinessException(e);});

     System.out.println("Returning Map created beanMap="+beanMap);

         return beanMap;
    }
```

All methods are executing parallely and I am getting beanMap as expected with the combined data. But the problem is main thread is returning the beanMap to the caller method before all other parallel threads are getting completed. So its returning an empty map to the caller. What is the right way of implementing parallel calls here?

Comment: you complain on main thread but do not show the code it runs. How do you think we can help you?

Comment: Hi Alexei, I am invoking findData(param1,param2) method from a rest service class( JAX-RS)  and I need to manipulate the data in service which is returning from findData method. Also each method in the observable are DB Look ups. I am trying to lookup data from DB parallely and try to return to my service class. I am running it in a Tomcat container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to convert the `Observable` to a `BlockingObservable`:

```
mergedBean1.toBlocking().subscribe(...);
```

This will wait until the source Observable completes. However, why not simply return an `Observable<Map>`? This way you don't need to explicitly wait, and you can compose this with other parallel operations.

Further, your code should be more or less equivalent to the following:

```
Observable.just(
     Observable.defer(() -> Observable.just(method1(param1,param2))),
     Observable.defer(() -> Observable.just(method1(param1,param2))),
     Observable.defer(() -> Observable.just(method1(param1,param2))),
     Observable.defer(() -> Observable.just(method1(param1,param2))),
     Observable.defer(() -> Observable.just(method1(param1,param2))),
     Observable.defer(() -> Observable.just(method1(param1,param2)))
)
.map(o -> o.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()))
.compose(Observable::merge)
.doOnNext(s -> combineDataMethod(s,beanMap))
.doOnError(e -> System.out.println("Exception happened while calculating Data"))
.onErrorResumeNext(e -> Observable.error(new BusinessException(e)))
.toBlocking()
.subscribe();
```

Comment: Thanks Tassos, Let me try this

Comment: Hi @Tassos I am getting an error saying "The method toBlocking() is undefined for the type Observable<List<DataDTO>>".

Comment: Thanks @Tassos it worked. i used blockingSubscribe()